# How to change standard email to exchange email account?

Tags: email, windows-10, gmail, windows-10-desktop, smime

**What are the things I used :**

  **I acquire my S/MIME certificate from ACTALIS .

  I used my GMAIL account.**

I want to add S/MIME certificate to my email. But mail client(Mail in windows) said , " **This setting can't be applied to any of your account** ". I found that S/MIME certificate is only applicable for exchange account. But I don't know about, how to change standard account to exchange account.

Comment: I‘d assume the message is trying to tell you that the email address in your certificate and the one configured in your email account do not match. Do they?

Comment: Do not they . The email was same as identical.